# JQuery/AJAX script not sending data to php file?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a question/status posting system using JQuery and Ajax however an error is being displayed `"Notice: Undefined index: status in C:\xampp\htdocs\deadline\data.php on line 5"` which is my line of code `"$var = $_POST['status']; "`

My system works as you have to log in to post a question(using sessions) **BUT** the issue is with my JQuery/AJAX script as the data that I have on **homepage.php** is not being sent to **data.php** (from my understanding which is why my index 'status' is undefined).

**MY CODE**

```html
    <?php
    include("connection.php");

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] != "") {
      
     }

       else {

      header("location:login.php");
     }

    $sid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='{$sid}'";

     $query = $conn->query($sql);

    $result = $query->fetch_assoc();

    $fname = $result['fname'];

    $lname = $result['lname'];

    $time = time();

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //daddy code
    $ (document).ready(function() {

    //mama code
    $("button#postbutton").click(function() {
    //children code
    var status = $("textarea#status").value();

    if(status == "") {
     return false;
    }

    var data = 'status='+status;

    $.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "data.php",

    data: data,

    success: function(data) {

    $("#statustext").html(data);

    }

    });


    });

    });

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>


    <div id="global">

    <form action="" onsubmit="return false">

    <textarea id="status"></textarea>


    <button id="postbutton">POST</button>

    <a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>

    </form>

    <br/>
    <br/>


    <div id="allstatus">



    <!-- SKELETON -->


    <div id="status">


    <div id="statuspic">
    </div>


    <div id="statusinfo">

    <div id="statusname">JOnathan</div>
    <div id="statustext"> this is the question</div>
    <div id="statusoption"><button id="likestatus">LIKE</button></div>
    <div id="statusoption"><button id="commentstatus">COMMENT</button></div>
    <div id="statusoption"><button id="sharestatus">SHARE</button></div>
    <div id="statusoption"><button id="statustime">TIME</button></div>

    </div>

    </div> 

    <!-- SKELETON -->

    </div>

    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

```
    <?php

    $var = $_POST['status'];

    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASS = '';
    const DB_NAME = 'forum';
    //connecting 

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {

    echo " success";

    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `question`(id, question) VALUES ('', '{$var}')";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result) {

     echo "inserted successfuly";
    }
     else {

      echo "failed: " . $conn->error;
     }


    echo " the text: " .$var. " has been added to database.";


    ?>
```

**HOW IT SHOULD WORK**

I want to use JQuery/AJAX on my **homepage.php** to send data to **data.php** and that data gets returned back to **homepage.php**. On success to be displayed in my div #statustext.

Meaning when i write a question in textarea input field the data gets stored in database and retrieved and displayed in my div on the browser.
Please help me thanks..

Comment: in which way you want to post data?

Comment: using post method. The way i have written the JQuery code in my first code snippet I posted ( which is homepage.php).

Comment: this is not the way to send data to a POST method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your script like below. Ajax sends data to url in a serialize manner either you have to use form serialize which will send all the fileds info to your php url other wise if you have to send only one field value then you can do this change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //daddy code
    $ (document).ready(function() {
        //mama code
        $("button#postbutton").click(function() {
            //children code
            var status = $("textarea#status").value();
            if(status == "") {
                return false;
            }
            var data = {'status='+status};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#statustext").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

POST uses `name` and not `id` so change this:

```
<textarea id="status"></textarea>
```

To this:

```
<textarea name="status"></textarea>
```

For the data make sure it's the data for your form, and add `method="post"` to it so it can send POST data. For example if you gave your form an id of `yourForm`:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="yourForm" onsubmit="return false">
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: $("#yourForm").serialize(), 
    ...
});
```

Comment: sorry i mean i want to post it without php, i thought i was doing it the right way as i wanted to post data through ajax. thats why i have onsubmit = "return false" ?

Comment: @LinDanChongWei AJAX uses PHP and POST data. I'm not saying you need to submit your form, but to get the information from your form in the AJAX call.

Comment: @LinDanChongWei Did you send your form data along with change `id` to `name`?

Comment: yes i did, could you show me a snippet maybe so i know what am doing wrong?

Comment: @LinDanChongWei Unfortunately I cannot as snippets are client sided only. Just noticed something, you need to add `method="post"` to your `<form>`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `.val()` not `.value()` when you getting value of your message. Second mistake - is using two `id = "sattus"`. Id of elements must be unique or use `class = ""` for ident your class of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give same id to more then 1 html element !

In your code :

```
<textarea id="status"></textarea>
```

and

```
<div id="status">
```

both contains same id ! Please correct it first.Also In your code as Spencer mentioned in his answer that add name attribute with value "status". No doubt as you are using jQuery selector it should pick up correct one,though you can just alert it before sending the request using AJAX.

also set data variable as `var data = {status : status};`